# how to add a (element) tag after each form element in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to add **h** tag after a group of elements so that i can put them sectionwise in zend form. Please help me! I want to create like

```
section1
    element1
    element2
section2
    element3
    element4
```

and i want to replace section by **h** tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add hidden element with label and set `escape=>false` in decorator

```
 $html = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('html');
        $html->setLabel('<div id="some-id">lorem ippsum</div>')
             ->setIgnore(true)
             ->addDecorator('Label', array('escape' => false));
```